# Temporary disabling of registrations in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails 5 project and I would like to temporarily disable new user registrations.  I know I can remove the view's link, or edit the routes file to accomplish this, but that requires a change to code with a new deployment.  I would like to add an option in my administrative console to disable the ability for new users to register for a period of time.

I have this functionality enabled, but it's a hacky work around.  When I disable the ability for people to register, all I am currently doing is hiding the 'new user registration' link in the devise view.  Anyone who knows the default paths can work around this.

How can I change this functionality at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow [This](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system) Link for overriding the Registration Controllers for Devise.
Basically you need to override Devise default Registeration controller and put up a before filter for `new & create` action which checks if admin allows to create new users if not then redirect to `root_path` or whatever path you want.

Alter the devise_for line in config/routes.rb to override the registration controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations"}
```

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :check_new_registration_allowed?, only: [:new, :create]

  protected

  def check_new_registration_allowed?
    redirect_to root_path unless @@allow_new_registration
  end

end
```

Please be noted that I used `@@allow_new_registration` global variable to check if new registration is allowed. You can turn this  on/off after admin action. Alternatively it would be good if you store these information in DB and query it.

Comment: Upvoted & marked as the answer.  Thank you for sending this - very helpful!